# in spite of the slight frost

Tags: sentence-meaning

The Adventure of the Blue Carbuncle

> The goose we retained until this morning, when there were signs that, **in spite of the slight frost**, it would be well that it should be eaten without unnecessary delay.

Question:

Can "in spite of the slight frost" be considered as parenthesis?

According to Holmes, the goose should be eaten without further delay. But why did he mention "the slight frost"? Did the slight frost imply any logical connection with eating the goose?

Answer (score 8):

'In spite of the slight frost' is a parenthetical expression. It adds additional information. The goose was visibly on the verge of being rotten. Birds and animals can be cooked and eaten a while after death, but there comes a time when the meat is bad to eat (spoiled, due to biological decomposition). This process is prolonged by low temperatures, but even considering the slight frost (temperature near to freezing point) that time was visibly near for the goose. The exterior takes on a green or grey colour.

People who eat game birds such as geese vary in their opinion of how long the dead bird should be 'hung' after death. Three to seven days at 10 to 12 degrees Celsius is usual for geese, depending on age. During that time decomposition starts and is considered to develop the flavour. A bird that has been hung for a long time is said to be 'high'. Clearly this goose would soon be too high for anyone to eat, even the most confirmed game lovers.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this is a parenthetical phrase, set off by commas.

I don't know the context, but I'd assume that this implies that the speaker means that there were signs that the goose was becoming rotten. It was becoming rotten despite the slight frost, which would be expected to preserve the meat for longer.

The "logical" connection is that cold temperatures preserve meat. In an age without refrigeration, this was more significant than it is today.